# Matrix theory- Contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that for any 2 square matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $$(A+B)=(I+AA^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}C(I+B^*B)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ for some contraction matrix $C$.

I already proved that $(I+AA^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $(I+B^*B)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are invertible, so we must have 
$$C=(I+AA^*)^{\frac{-1}{2}}(A+B)(I+B^*B)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

The ways I know to prove a matrix $A$ to be a contraction are either the definition, $\|Ax\|\le c\|x\|$ for some $0\le c\le 1$

Or if all the singular values of $A$ are less than or equal to $1$

Or if $A$ is a finite convex combination of unitary matrices.

But I wasn't able to prove $C$ a contraction, can you help please?

Comment: My understanding is that the normal definition of [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) requires the constant $\ c\ $ to be *strictly less* than $1$. Do you require that, or is it sufficient for your purposes that $\ c\ $ merely not exceed $1$?

Comment: You're talking about the definition of contraction in functions, but in matrices it is okay to have $c=1$, and if $c<1$ then it will be called strict contraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=U_1S_1V_1^\ast$ and $B=U_2S_2V_2^\ast$ be two singular value decompositions. Then $W_1=V_1^\ast V_2$ and $W_2=U_1^\ast U_2$ are unitary. Let $X_k=S_k(I+S_k^2)^{-1/2}$ and $Y_k=(I+S_k^2)^{-1/2}$ for $k=1,2$. Then $X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2$ are diagonal matrices such that $X_1^2+Y_1^2=X_2^2+Y_2^2=I$. Hence $\pmatrix{X_1&Y_1}$ has orthonormal rows and $\pmatrix{Y_2\\ X_2}$ has orthonormal columns. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\|C\|
&=\left\|U_1(I+S_1^2)^{-1/2}U_1^\ast\left(U_1S_1V_1^\ast + U_2S_2V_2^\ast\right)V_2(I+S_2^2)^{-1/2}V_2^\ast\right\|\\
&=\|U_1(X_1W_1Y_2+Y_1W_2X_2)V_2^\ast\|\\
&=\|X_1W_1Y_2+Y_1W_2X_2\|\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{X_1&Y_1}\pmatrix{W_1\\ &W_2}\pmatrix{Y_2\\ X_2}\right\|\\
&\le\left\|\pmatrix{X_1&Y_1}\right\|\left\|\pmatrix{W_1\\ &W_2}\right\|\left\|\pmatrix{Y_2\\ X_2}\right\|\\
&=1.
\end{aligned}